# Do we try to prevent cycles in temporal logic (CTL)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, first-order-logic

When looking at the formulas for the rules in CTL, it is said that we save the states we have already been in a in list/ set. Does that mean that we are trying to preven endless loops?
[image]
For example given the model in the picture if we wanna check for EG, do we way that that  $EG q$ holds true for {s0, s3, s0, s3, s0, s3, .....} or just {s0, s3}, it is my understanding that once we visite one state we can't get back to it?